# The "Reject Feedback" text area is too short

Tags: feature-request, bug

So when I go to reject a change, I am presented with large dialog: I am rejecting this change because..."Other" - Be specific! But then you don't give me enough room in the text box to actually be specific. My critique tends to be a bit wordy, because I'm interested in being specific, detailed, and a bit conversational. Can we get something larger for feedback?